# Azure Bot Framework with Cognitive Speech not working

Tags: javascript, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service

I'm following [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/master/docs-samples/web-chat-speech/index.html) where we can use the Speech recognition in the bot framework.

The default code is working with *Option 2*,

```
  // // Option 2: Native browser speech (not supported by all browsers, no speech recognition priming support)
  //
  // Note that Chrome automatically blocks speech if the HTML file is loaded from disk. You can run a server locally
  // or launch Chrome (close all the existing Chrome browsers) with the following option:
  // chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files <sampleHtmlFile>
  //
  const speechOptions = {
     speechRecognizer: new BotChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechRecognizer(),
     speechSynthesizer: new BotChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer()
  };
```

But when I tried to use cognitive services it's not working, meaning the mic is not going to listening mode.

This is the change I made,

```
      // // Option 3: Cognitive Services speech recognition using API key (cross browser, speech priming support)
 const speechOptions = {
        speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ subscriptionKey: 'YOUR_COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY' }),
        speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
          gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
          subscriptionKey: 'YOUR_COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY',
          voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
        })
      };
```

Apart from the commenting and uncommenting i didn't do any thing. But still the code is working only with **Option 2**

Pls help me solve this

Comment: There was a similar issue related to this thread - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/687
Please check and see if it helps.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT thanks for the link. I think it's not related to that issue since I tried with almost all browsers like Chrome, Firefox, and Edge because cognitive can work in cross platform browsers. I tired with all different one. None of them works when I click the mike icon, the browsers got struct and going to the listening mode in none of the browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some deep digging from my colleague, we found the issue.

The original code is using the javascript from [`https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js`](https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js)

```
 <div id="BotChatGoesHere"></div>


    <!-- If you do not want to use Cognitive Services library, comment out the following line -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>
```

If we open that JS file, you can find a line like below where it's using bing speech url

```
Storage.Local.GetOrAdd("Host","wss://speech.platform.bing.com")}
```

Since **bing speech is depricted**  we have to update this line into our own subsciption

```
Storage.Local.GetOrAdd("Host","wss://<region>.stt.speech.microsoft.com")}
```

Once we updated it's working fine now

Comment: I have the same problem, could you maybe share the updated code? I don't understand the last thing. Where to update and what? @Jayendran

Comment: @MarcoWirtl in the `CognitiveServices.js` file there is a specific line where you need to update it. That line is `Storage.Local.GetOrAdd("Host","wss://speech.platform.bing.com")` you have to update it like `Storage.Local.GetOrAdd("Host","wss://<region>.stt.speech.microsoft.com")`

Comment: So I downloaded the JS and changed the link, also changed <region> to westus and load the script with ./CognitiveServices.js the button is still not clickable. What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry no idea what is wrong. Because for us after doing this it worked

Comment: Whats about the sub Keys? Are this both the same? From the Speech Cognitive Service?

Comment: this should make speechRecognizer works, to make speechSynthesizer work too you need to change two extra URLs "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" to be https://<region>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken and _synthesisURL "https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize" to be  https://<region>.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1